# GNU sed json replace function issues

Tags: json, awk, sed

**Background**

Original json (`test.json`): `{ "umask": 1 }`

Expected changed json: `{ "umask": 2 }`

`replace_json_str` is a function used to replace `1` with `2` using `gnu sed`.

```
replace_json_str() {
    x=$1
    sed -i -e 's/\({ "'"$2"'":\)"[^"]*" }/\1"'"$3"'" }/g' $x
}
```

Unit test: `replace_json_str test.json umask 2`

**Issue**

After running the unit test, the `test.json` does not change to the expected as noted above, why?

Comment: for such simple json string, why not just use a single `sed` command replacement without a function?

Comment: I am using this in a larger shell program.

Comment: Because your regex is looking for `{ "umask":"..." }`.

Comment: @melpomene How would I get it to work with `{ "umask": 1 }`?

Comment: wrt `I am using this in a larger shell program.` - that's a big red flag. A shell is for sequencing calls to tools and creating/destroying files and processes. If youre doing something else with it, e.g. manipulating text as in your question, then you're using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sed -i 's/(test\.json): { "umask": '"$1"' }/{ "umask": '"$2"' }/' "$x"
```